# Multiline equations using LaTex in Apple Apps

Tags: equations

I am new to LaTeX, love it. I'm trying to type multiline equations within [Apple Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pages_(word_processor))s since [MathType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType) doesn't support Mac Apps anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Pages > Insert > Equation and use an `align` environment like shown

[image]

Comment: Should the `=` instead be `&=` so that the alignment point is defined? I think in the image the equal signs look aligned as the `b` and `x` are of similar width. If you replace the `b` with `byz` the effect should be more obvious.

Comment: @PeterGrill You are right. It was a typo on my part. I edited in the forgotten `&`.

Comment: Apple Pages? Do you mean you're using Pages as an Editor for LaTeX?

Comment: @HerbSchulz No, but you can insert a quick equation into your document using LaTeX or MathML formatting which is what I think the question is asking.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!